# Container view controller in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In iOS app I have a widget, a menu that is part of all my screen. Is it possible in Android to nest activity into other activity, and so widget in outer activity is able to see in inner activity? I want avoid any code duplication, redundancy.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted. I'm an iOS engineer and was trying to understand the right terminology to use with my Android colleagues to discuss this concept. The answer below really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). An activity cannot contain another activity. About the navigation components, you can always check the [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and use the **tabs** component or the **navigation view**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In android, you could implement it using [Tab](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html) with fragments inside it.

Answer (score 0):

in android, `Fragment` is designed for these situations.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html